# .desktop and /bin files are included in /opt/extras.ubuntu.com/<package> with Quickly

Tags: application-development, quickly

In the [Guidelines](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppReviewBoard/Review/Guidelines#Packaging) for the Ubuntu App Showdown I can read:

> The .desktop file is installed in the standard location
>   /usr/share/applications, but must have the prefix 'extras-' added to
>   its name. Example: extras-foobar.desktop for a package named foobar.

Then I renamed *pyenglish.desktop.in* to *extras-pyenglish.desktop.in* and changed the setup.py line 57 to: 
`fin = file('extras-pyenglish.desktop.in', 'r')`

And run this command for using /opt with Quickly:

```
quickly package --extras
```

- The desktop file is included in /opt/extras.ubuntu.com/*package*/share/applications/.desktop
- The bin file is included in /opt/extras.ubuntu.com/*package*/bin/

**The problem is that Ubuntu not found the app in the system** :(

How could I change this behavior? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to rename the .desktop file, Quickly will take care of it for you.

The point of using Quickly is that you don't have to worry about the requirements and don't have to change files manually, as Quickly will automate it transparently for you.

So I would recommend undoing the changes in `setup.py` and renaming the .desktop file back to the original `pyenglish.desktop.in`, and then run `quickly package --extras` again.

After that, the *.desktop* and *binary* file locations should be:

- `/usr/share/applications/extras-pyenglish.desktop`
- `/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/pyenglish/bin/pyenglish`

That will allow you starting PyEnglish from the Unity Dash as usual. Note that if you want to start it from the terminal, you'll either need to call it explicitly as `/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/pyenglish/bin/pyenglish` or add `/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/pyenglish/bin/` to your `$PATH`